# Header Size Issues

Tags: html, css, header, heading

The header of my website is 1300px width. A scrollbar appears at the bottom, allowing me to scroll over the image (because the header size it's bigger than my screen size).

Is there any code where I can delete that scrollbar and show the header image that my screen allows to show? I don't know If you understand what I mean...

Comment: You're probably looking for overflow:hidden in your css, but a code snippit would help to be sure

Answer (score 0):

The above comment using overflow:hidden is correct.

However, from you description it sounds like the image is not a background image added by CSS, but a live image using an  tag. If that's the case you have a couple options:

1. Set the width of the image to 100% and the height to "auto" (using CSS of course)
2. Set the image to be the background image of the header and size from there.

I could keep going but as the commenter above said, without code etc to look at we're forced to totally guess what you're really trying to accomplish.

Comment: You're right Im sorry! this is the code of the image <div id="header"> <img src="http://i.imgur.com/0VxmlM1.png"/> </div> And as you said, It's not a background image added with css

Comment: So if you want the whole image to fit, but no scroll, set the image width or max-width to 100%, but if it's okay for the image to cut off on a smaller screen apply the overflow:hidden; to the image's parent element.